# Is it possible to override type-error behavior in Common Lisp upon out-of-range values for limited-range variables?

Tags: error-handling, integer, range, common-lisp

Sorry if the question's topic is oddly phrased (for lack of better terminology -- also one of the reasons I didn't find anything Googling this specific topic), so here's what I mean with an example.

Let's say this function foobar is defined:

```
(defun foobar (x)
  (declare (type (integer -100 100) x))
  (format T "X is ~A~%" x))
```

So with the declare line, x is an integer that must be -100, 100, or any integer in-between.  Thus, doing this yields an error:

```
CL-USER> (foobar 101)

The value 101 is not of type (INTEGER -100 100).
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]

   Restarts:
   (blah blah blah)
```

Short of changing the function itself to explicitly do clamping, is there a way to specify an override behavior such that doing this, without altering the defun of foobar itself:

```
(foobar [any-value-over-100])
```

Clamps it to 100, and likewise with x < -100, without the function body itself having extra lines of code to do so?

Edit:  To answer one responder, this is clamping -- keeping a value strictly within a defined minimum and maximum range.  In Lisp, this is an example:

```
CL-USER> (defun clamp (x min max)
    (if (> x max)
        max
        (if (< x min)
            min
            x)))
CLAMP
CL-USER> (clamp 5 4 9)
5
CL-USER> (clamp -2 4 9)
4
CL-USER> (clamp 123 4 9)
9
```

While I can easily just make this a macro and put it in the beginning of any function (and I have an odd feeling this'll ultimately be what I'll have to do), this question is asking whether it's possible to tell the Common Lisp error handler to "just do this with the values instead!", rather than having it interrupting the entire program flow as it normally does.

Answer (score 1):

## Ignore Declarations

If you compile the function with [the appropriate settings](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_optimi.htm), the type declaration will be ignored.

## Redefine Function

Alternatively, you can redefine your function like this:

```
(defparameter *foobar-orig* (fdefinition *foobar*))
(defun foobar (x)
  (funcall *foobar-orig* (whatever-you-want x)))
```

## Use restarts

Your best way forward is to replace declarations with [`check-type`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_check_.htm) and establish appropriate [handlers](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_handle.htm), e.g.,

```
(handler-bind ((type-error 
                 (lambda (c)
                   (let ((et (type-error-expected-type c))) 
                     (store-value (clamp (type-error-datum c) (second et) (third et)))))))
  (let ((x 100)) 
    (check-type x (integer 1 10)) 
    (print x)))
```

The standard does not provide for *global* error handlers, but implementations [usually do](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/restarts.html#global-handler).

Comment: I wasn't able to put properly-formatted code in this reply, so I edited my original post to explain the clamp function.  I didn't want the type declaration to be ignored, but rather so it would behave differently instead of calling an error if an integer was out of boundaries of a ranged-integer type declaration.  I prefer having (INTEGER [min] [max]) type declarations because it helps the compiler in certain optimizations, and also helps with the whole "self documenting code" idea when doing (describe 'foobar) at the REPL, which will then faithfully describe that parameter's type declaration.

Answer (score 1):

**Type declarations in Common Lisp**

Your code:

```
(defun foobar (x)
  (declare (type (integer -100 100) x))
  (format T "X is ~A~%" x))
```

The consequences of call above with something like `(foobar 120)` are entirely undefined in Common Lisp.

- it may be completely ignored
- it may lead to errors or various runtime problems
- it may help the compiler to create better code (this is btw. the main reason for those declarations)
- it may be typed checked at compile / or runtime. Only very few Lisp compilers do it.

**Portable runtime type checking in Common Lisp**

If you want to portably check for runtime type errors use `CHECK-TYPE` or `ASSERT`.

```
(defun foobar (x)
  (check-type x (integer -100 100))
  (format T "X is ~A~%" x))
```

**Advising**

Extending functions without changing their source code is called 'advising' in Lisp. This is not in the Common Lisp standard for normal functions, but there should be tools for it and it is not that difficult to write such a thing.

**Extending Generic Functions**

Common Lisp has this mechanism built-in for *generic functions*. The *standard method combination* has :before, :after and :around advising.

```
(defmethod foobar ((x integer))
  (check-type x (integer -100 100))
  (format T "X is ~A~%" x))
```

In Common Lisp one cannot dispatch on arbitrary types - only on classes. There are classes for basic types like string, integer, ... Here we use that `x` is an `integer`.

If you want to *clamp* `foobar`'s `x`:

```
(defmethod foobar :around ((x integer))
  (call-next-method (clamp x -200 100)))
```

Above is an `:around` method. I calls the next method, the one above, with a changed argument. This is allowed as long as the argument class does not change the dispatch.

**Alternative approach: Macro**

One goal might be to write less code and have code more declarative.

Maybe one wants to write:

```
(defun-clamped foobar ((x (integer :min -100 :clampled-max 100)))
  (format T "X is ~A~%" x))
```

Then I would just write the `defun-clamped` macro, which expands into a normal `DEFUN`, which does the necessary things.

Comment: I think the solution I'll go with will be a combination of your macro suggestion along with sds's mention of (declare (optimize (safety 0))) -- in SBCL at least, safety setting of 0 lets me give a function with a ranged-value parameter an out-of-bounds value for that parameter without an error occuring, and still showing the proper (INTEGER -100 100) type declaration when using the DESCRIBE function.  So I can then, as you suggest, write a custom-made "enhanced defun" macro that defines functions with that 0 safety setting and then inserts the custom clamping code into the function's prologue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to ensure the integer to be in that range, if that is the case I don't think you should handle it with type error, but a (let ...) something like this:

```
(defun ensure-range (x low high)
  (cond ((< x low) low)
        ((> x high) high)
        (t x)))

(defun foobar (x)
  (let (x (ensure-range x -100 100))
    (format T "X is ~A~%" x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare x to be between -100 and 100 if you can accept something else. I think that an implementation might be free to allow any kinds of memory corruption if a declaration is violated.
So, doing

```
(declare (optimize (safety 0)))
```

to avoid the declaration throwing an error is not really a good idea.
You can first clamp the value and then put the rest of the function definition into a LET form.

```
(defun foo (x)
  (declare (type integer x))
  (let ((x (clamp x -100 100)))
    (declare (type (integer -100 100)  ; LET allows declarations, too!
                   x))
    (bar x)))
```

If you want a macro to do this for you, something like the following should work:

```
(defmacro defclamp (name (arg min max)
                    &body body)
  `(defun ,name (,arg)
     (declare (type real ,arg))
     (let ((,arg (clamp ,arg ,min ,max)))
       (declare (type (real ,min ,max)
                      ,arg))
       ,@body)))
```

Comment: I didn't consider memory corruption, though I see how the "safety 0" solution might come back to haunt me later even if it is "just working" right now.  I think, then, I'll expand upon the custom defun macro I wrote to force-translate ranged types to unranged equivalent ones, and then keep a record of those special clamped  parameters in the game's API for functions that have them.  I'll then write a customized, API-specific equivalent of 'describe' that does what Lisp's vanilla 'describe' doesn't/can't do, including displaying that kind of parameter detail to end users (scripters/modders).